# How can I export the OfflineAudioContext rendered audio buffer to a ogg,wav or mp3 file?

Tags: android, cordova, audio, web-audio-api

I am trying to mix user recorded MP3 with some music in Cordova application, if I use just audioContext and MediaRecorder with pushing chunks to the array I could export to ogg format. It doesn't work with offline audio context, because mediaRecorder works in real time, the destination stream is always empty in case of offline audio context.

Irrespective of which audioContext I use is there any way I can convert audioBuffers to wav/mp3 within Cordova application?

Comment: There's possible strategy of splitting audio buffer into multiple parts and feeding to multiple media recorders in parallel, then recomposing results into a single blob. The speed will be limited by max number of recorders allowed and min encoded chunk duration, I'd expect 200ms delay.